# Retrieve max value from table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have table with followin attributes

h_id , name , .....

And i want to return max Id that occurs in table.

I am using

```
"select max(h.h_id) from Hospital h"
```

which throws

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement

What is the riht way to do it?

// edit , the code

```
    public static Integer getHospitalId(){
        List<Integer> ids = null;
        try {
            Query q = session.createQuery ("select max(h.h_id) from Hospital h");
            ids = (List<Integer>)q.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if( ids!= null)
            return ids.get(0) + 1;
        return new Integer(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that that's the query causing the constraint violation? Maybe if you shared some code and the full stack trace, you could get better answers.

Comment: added example of the code

Comment: Why you are using `list()`?

Comment: Iam using list bcs im going step by step with tutorial , also i couldnt find a way how to do it without list

Comment: You are looking for the max value of the `h_id` column in the table `Hospital`. Is `Hospital` an entity? If it is, then you should ensure that `h_id` is the class variable name, or change the query to match the class variable name.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this way:

```
SELECT max(h_id) FROM Hospital
```